# React Router-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

React route is not behaving as expected when trying to define my routes.Here is the file where i've defined my route `routes.js`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
);
```

And here is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router,browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes';
import reducers from './reducers';



const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={ browserHistory } routes={ routes } />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

When i run npm start i get the following error in the browser debugger `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined`.So to figure it out i've tried to installe the version `3.2.0` of `react-router` as said in the following discussion: [React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184178/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-func-of-undefined) from `Stackoverflow` and [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5605) from `github`  because the version of `react-dom` that i'm using is `2.0.0-rc5` because that is the version used by the instructor of the course and in the video it works fine but not i my computer

Comment: Can you also specify the version of React.js your are using? It might be a compatibility issue between the two

Comment: My react version is `16.3.2`

Comment: it may have worked with this install but fresh installs may get various peer / transient deps due to semver diffs.